# Auto adjust table row height keeping width fixed

Tags: css

I have a table containing many rows. I can allow a change in row height to fill the contents, but I want to keep my cell width fixed. Setting a `max-width` to cell solves the problem, but the content over flows to the next cell.. Can anybody have a solution in html/css or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `max-width`, set `overflow: hidden;`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/andyedinborough/nq7rA/1/

Comment: no.. it won't display the remaining text.. i need the remaining text

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap?